# How do you perform javascript tests with Minitest, Capybara, Selenium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, capybara, minitest

There are a lot of examples on how to perform javascript tests with Capybara/Selenium/**Rspec** in which you can write a test like so:

```
it "does something", :js => true do
  ...
end
```

However with **minitest** you can't pass a second parameter to instruct selenium to perform the test.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: How to use Js on Test::Unit is [now covered on the docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/4161bbc560631e61e611d59bf797eeb59a6b1021/README.md#using-capybara-with-testunit). Says to use the verbose `Capybara.current_driver = ` like current answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I noticed a couple lines in the docs that seem to say that the above can only be done in Rspec

However, if you are using **RSpec or Cucumber**, you may instead want to consider leaving the faster `:rack_test` as the `default_driver`, and marking only those tests that require a     JavaScript-capable driver `using :js => true` or `@javascript`, respectively.

Comment: You can't specify :js => true at the ```it "should do this" do``` level in minitest. Only in the main ```describe``` block.

Answer (score 18):

What `:js` flag is doing is very simple. It switches the current driver from default (rack-test) to another one that supports javascript execution (selenium, webkit). You can do the same thing in minitest:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

class WebsiteTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def teardown
    super
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end

  def test_with_javascript
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
    visit "/"
    click_link "Hide"
    assert has_no_link?("Hide")
  end

  def test_without_javascript
    visit "/"
    click_link "Hide"
    assert has_link?("Hide")
  end
end
```

Of course you can abstract this into a module for convenience:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

module PossibleJSDriver
  def require_js
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
  end

  def teardown
    super
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end
end

class MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  include PossibleJSDriver
end

class WebsiteTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_with_javascript
    require_js
    visit "/"
    click_link "Hide"
    assert has_no_link?("Hide")
  end

  def test_without_javascript
    visit "/"
    click_link "Hide"
    assert has_link?("Hide")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/wojtekmach/minitest-metadata seems to have provided a solution to exactly this.

You can do the following:

```
describe "something under test" do
  it "does not use selenium for this test" do
    visit "/"
    assert body.has_content?("Hello world")
  end

  it "does use selenium for this test", :js => true do
    visit "/"
    click_link "Hide" # a link that uses a javascript click event, for example
    assert body.has_no_link?("Hide")
  end
end
```

Comment: minitest-capybara actually does not offer this feature

Comment: IMHO this answers the OP's question more accurately, as using the `minitest-metadata` gem allows you to pass a `:js => true` hash to the `it` block, exactly as you can in RSpec. This avoids the need for a method call in each test method, as in the accepted answer. The answer would have been improved if it had included the `:before` and `:after` blocks from the gem's README (see link), rather than the incomplete code shown. https://github.com/wojtekmach/minitest-metadata#example-with-capybara

Answer (score 0):

Just to update some information, there is a more powerful selenium-webdriver with [Ruby Bindings](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings) now.

To test JavaScript on firefox from terminal quickly with Rails 4 and selenium-webdriver, you need to do the 4 steps below:

1. Add gem to your Gemfile

   gem 'selenium-webdriver'
   gem 'minitest-rails'
2. Install gem

   bundle install
3. Generate test case (Ref: [Official Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html))

   bin/rails generate integration_test your_case_name
4. Start to write test code in your test case.
   Actually you can write it in ruby without Capybara, to write case with Capybara you can refer to [Capybara at Github](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)

Minitest sample:

```
# create a driver
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
# navigate to a page
driver.navigate.to 'url_to_page'
# get element with class box
box = driver.find_element(:css, '.box')

# check width
# get width by execute JavaScript
assert_equal 100, driver.execute_script('return $(arguments[0]).width()', box)
```

Currently it seems lack of resources with respect to how to work with selenium-webdriver, CI server (Jenkins) and Rails minitest smoothly, I have created a simple project and hope it can help any one getting started quickly and easily: 
[Rails Selenium Working Case](https://github.com/benbai123/RubyOnRails/tree/master/Practice/RubyOnRails/Test/Selenium/WorkinCase/SeleniumTest)

Also appreciate the comments that let me can make better answer.

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: Just linking to your own library is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code using the library to do so and disclaiming makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/200235)