# Javascript not getting executed when running Capybara (with Minitest)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, minitest

When running my tests, javascript isn't getting executed. I tried switching from the :selenium driver to the :webkit driver, but still no luck.

It works fine in the browser. When the test runs and the page opens, the page is blank

Is there something else I need to do to get it to execute javascript during test runs?

business_integration_test.rb

```
require 'minitest_helper'
require 'ruby-debug'

describe "Business integration" do

  before :each do
    @business = Factory.build(:business)
    Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
  end

  it "Should show error if business name is blank" do
    visit admin_business_path
    fill_in 'Name', :with => ''
    click_button 'Save'
    page.save_and_open_page
    page.text.must_include("can't be blank")
  end
end
```

businesses_controller.rb

```
class Admin::BusinessesController < Admin::AdminController

  def update
    @business = resource
    respond_to do |format|
      if @business.update_attributes(params[:business])
        flash[:notice] = "Your business was updated successfully."
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Your business failed to update."
      end
      format.js { render :template => "admin/businesses/edit" }
    end
  end

end
```

edit.js.erb

```
$("#page-businesses #main").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'edit_information') %>");
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I have tried https://github.com/clnclarinet/minitest-capybara but it doesn't work with current capybara version.

Comment: [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655154/how-do-you-perform-javascript-tests-with-minitest-capybara-selenium?rq=1) asks as similar question. I'm having this problem as well.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/wojtekmach/minitest-metadata It might help.